# Working with storyboards in Xcode, how to handle massive Storyboard in iOS

Tags: objective-c, xcode, storyboard

I have been using the storyboard to make an application and currently there are many segues and several components. This is causing a ton of lag when I try to do anything inside the storyboard. Is there a way to hide components inside the storyboard? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

+1, For the potentially features to improve Xcode. Now, there is no way you can hide those views (Not that I know). But I would suggest you to,

- Hide the debug areas you don't need.
- Hide the document outline while working with segues.

#### Why?

I think in this way whenever you are making changes, system does not have to repaint those unwanted views and long document outline. Probably this will be less laggy(I don't think there is a word like this)!

---

## Work around

Divide your segue into different meta segues and then you can call those segues from your main segue. In that way you don't have to put each connection on one file but you condense it!

And here we go the documentation for it! Now you can get the story board by different file and then initiate with the UIViewController easily. Then you can just use old ways to segue between different ViewControllers.

Apple Documentation for UIStoryboard

## Demo App.

In order to achieve this, I have made a quick demo application which will help any future visitors.

https://github.com/Krutarth/LargeStoryboardManagement

---

#### Visually something like this,

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately hiding the debug area and document outlines does not help my lag issue. I am unsure how to do the work around you posted, would you be able to elaborate, thanks!

Comment: Okay, I just updated with the Apple Doc reference. Basically you can invoke a storyboard which is inside a different .xib file. So the purpose is to breakdown the design structure of your storyboard into different related pieces. Then At any point of time in your program you may invoke the story board from a particular file :).I hope this will make sense. I will try to see if I can make a tutorial for it, but keep trying.

Comment: Ya I understand what you are saying, and I will keep trying to get it to work. If you could make a tutorial I would be so grateful, thanks for the help!

Comment: @chrisryan, here we go! download the repo and enjoy ;) https://github.com/Krutarth/LargeStoryboardManagement

Comment: @chrisryan, Make sure you accept the answer if you liked by answer! you can up vote and accept! its just a stackoverflow way to be grateful lol

Comment: YES! thank you so much, unfortunately this was my first post so I do not have enough rep to up vote, but I will accept, thanks again!

Comment: No worries! I am sure you will do this same thing to others in future. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can split one huge storyboard into multiple small storyboards. 
Select the view controllers that you want to move to a smaller storyboard, then

In the top menu, click Editor -> Refactor to Storyboard

Save the new storyboard with the desired name. XCode will auto generate all the required storyboard links from your large storyboard to this newly created small one.